# Prove (de Morgan 1) $\vdash A\wedge B \equiv \neg (\neg A \vee \neg B)$

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

Proof - starting from the right side:
$$\neg (\neg A \vee \neg B)$$
$<=>\text{(axiom: introduction of }\neg \text{)}$
$$\neg A \vee \neg B \equiv \bot $$
$<=> (\text{Leib + }\vdash\neg A\vee B\equiv A\vee B\equiv B\text{; 'C-part' is } p\equiv \bot)$
$$\neg A \vee B \equiv \bot \equiv A \vee B\equiv B \equiv \bot$$

I'm not sure what the next step is... from reviewing other answers somehow $$(\neg A \vee B \equiv \bot \equiv A \vee B\equiv B \equiv \bot)\equiv (A\vee\neg B\equiv \neg B \equiv \bot)$$

Comment: You clearly have some proof system you're using. I suspect many people don't know what you mean by "Leib" (though many would guess a use of Leibniz's law in some form) or what "C-part is $p\equiv\bot$" refers to. Of course, we can't know what equivalences you take as axioms. (Incidentally, you can make $\iff$ with `\iff`.)

Comment: thanks! I thought it was standard, but makes sense I need to be more explicit.

Comment: While it's reasonable to assume what classical propositional logic is is standard (though, not necessarily what exactly the *term* "classical propositional logic" refers to), there's a *huge* variety of presentations of proof systems and some variety in semantics. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_systems#Classical_propositional_calculus_systems) lists 12 sets of axioms for classical propositional logic just in the context of Hilbert-style proof systems in the language with only $\neg$ and $\to$.

Comment: Even with the same set of rules/axioms, the specific letters used are certainly not standard. I assume the "C-part" you refer to is the $E$ in Leibniz's Law described in [Equational Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic) referenced by Mauro ALLEGRANZA. In general, as you go deeper in a mathematical field, especially an old one, there tends to be much more variety and inconsistency in terminology and notation. Small distinctions become more important and different "schools" with their own conventions and approaches develop significant amounts of overlapping work independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your previous post, the proof uses to [Equational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic), following George Tourlakis, [Mathematical Logic (Wiley, 2008)](https://books.google.it/books?id=8jAwgCTgnycC&pg=PA42).

In order to prove **Th.2.4.17** (De Morgan-1) : $\vdash A \land B \equiv \lnot (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)$ [page 72], we have to start form the premise :

> 1) $¬(¬A \lor ¬B)$

and we have to transform it, through equivalences, into the conclusion.

The first step uses the axiom defining $\lnot$ : $\lnot A \equiv (A \equiv \bot)$ to get :

2) $(¬A \lor ¬B) \equiv \bot$.

The next step uses the previously proved **Coroll.2.4.12** : $\vdash \lnot A \lor B \equiv (A \lor B \equiv B)$ [page 70].

We need Leibniz's rule :

> from $D_1 \equiv D_2$ and $C[p:=D_1]$ derive $C[p:=D_2]$, where $C$ is a formula and $C[p:=D_i]$ is obtained from $C$ replacing part $p$ with formula $D_i$.

This means to use the 2) as $C$ and $(¬A \lor ¬B)$ as $D_1$ and $(A \lor \lnot B \equiv \lnot B)$ as $D_2$ to get :

3)  $(A \lor \lnot B \equiv \lnot B) \equiv \bot$

and thus, using the axiom for Assiociativity of $\equiv$ :

4) $A \lor \lnot B \equiv (\lnot B \equiv \bot)$.

Then using Leibniz again, the axiom for $\lnot$ and **Th.2.4.4** (Double Negation, page 67), we get :

5) $A \lor \lnot B \equiv B$.

Now we use the Corollary again : $\vdash (\lnot A \lor B \equiv A \lor B) \equiv B$. We have to replace in 5) $B$ with $\lnot A \lor B \equiv A \lor B$ to get :

6)  $A \lor \lnot B \equiv (\lnot A \lor B \equiv A \lor B)$

and thus :

7) $(A \lor \lnot B \equiv \lnot A \lor B) \equiv A \lor B$.

Here we need the following : $(A \lor \lnot B \equiv \lnot A \lor B) \equiv (A \equiv B)$ [I've not found it in the book : we may check it with truth table].

Using it and Simmetry of $\equiv$ we get :

8) $A \lor B \equiv (A \equiv B)$.

The last step uses the **Golden Rule** axiom : $A \land B \equiv (A \equiv B \equiv A \lor B)$ and we conclude with :

> > 9) $A \land B$.

---

*Note*: here is a proof of the "missing corollary" : $\vdash (A \lor \lnot B \equiv \lnot A \lor B) \equiv (A \equiv B)$

1) $(A \lor \lnot B \equiv \lnot A \lor B)$

2) $\lnot A \lor B \equiv A \lor B \equiv B$ --- **Coroll.2.4.12**

3) $\lnot B \lor A \equiv A \lor B \equiv A$ --- idem

Thus, using Leibniz twice :

3) $(A \lor B \equiv B) \equiv (A \lor B \equiv A)$.

Rearranging it :

4) $(A \lor B \equiv A \lor B) \equiv (A \equiv B)$.

By **Coroll.2.1.21** [page 59 : $(A \lor B \equiv A \lor B) \equiv \top$], we get :

5) $\top \equiv (A \equiv B)$

and thus, by **Coroll.2.1.21** again [$\vdash A \equiv (A \equiv \top)$]  :

> > 6) $(A \equiv B)$.